# How to auto click on image

Tags: vbscript

```
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.Application")   
IE.Visible = 1   
IE.navigate "https://dashboard.opendns.com/settings/"   
Do While (IE.Busy)   
WScript.Sleep 10   
Loop   
Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("username")   
Helem.Value = " "
Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("password")   
Helem.Value = " " 
IE.Application.document.getElementById("sign-in").Click
WScript.Sleep 10   


<a id="dip22332965" title="Update this text" href="#"
   onclick="update_ip(22332965);return false" img width="11" height="13" 
   style="border: 0pt none; margin-bottom: 1px;"
   src="https://d2v7u03x06aro3.cloudfront.net/img/icon_update_small.gif">
```

I successfully sign in after clicking the button, but how can I click on image automatically as mentioned above script?